# Run time user permission dialog not showing in Noughat

Tags: java, android

In my app run time app permissions are not showing in dialog and app crashes on opening the app in Noughat but its working fine in Marshmallow and other less API's. Please provide a quick solution for this problem. Thanks in advance

```
            @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);       
 }
  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:
        {
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                int perm=1;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also included user-permission tags in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Please add urs crash log here

Comment: your permission asking code seems to be working. Maybe you are trying to use some of the permission in activity`s onResume, can you post crash log and your whole activity code

Comment: thanks guys but my code itself works fine...its problem with the mobile and after some changes in settings app works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library

compile 'com.vistrav:ask:2.4'

And then ask for different permissions like

Ask.on(this).forPermissions(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,

android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET,

android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,

android.Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,

Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)

.go();

This will definitely work.